# How can I make VirtualBox guests share the host's VPN connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, router, routing, tunnel

**Question**

When I start my VPN on my ubuntu desktop computer which acts as a router, the attached subnet loses internet connectivity, but is still accessible (LAN). Ideally, I would like to know how to enable the attached subnet to re-gain internet access by routing through the VPN tunnel when the VPN is active.

**Context**

I have the following network layout:

subnet 172.16.0.0/20 on eth0 for my VirtualBox virtual machines.

subnet 192.168.0.0/24 on eth0:0 which connects to gateway 192.168.0.1  which has internet access.

This is shown in the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This is the subnet dedicated to VB
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.0.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.164
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

# normal DHCP internet
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.164
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

The packets on the eth0 are forwarded through eth0:0 with masquerading and normal internet connectivity is fine. However when I start my VPN tunnel on this router, internet connectivity is lost for the VMs on the eth0 subnet (yet remains for the router).

Below is the **output of ifconfig** when the tunnel is active:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:bc:01:c3:ab  
          inet addr:172.16.0.1  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21f:bcff:fe01:c3ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:165426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:182601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:208264321 (208.2 MB)  TX bytes:16660945 (16.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:bc:01:c3:ab  
          inet addr:192.168.0.164  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:381963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:381963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22755054 (22.7 MB)  TX bytes:22755054 (22.7 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.10  P-t-P:10.8.0.9  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I suspect that the solution will have something to do with the **routing table**. It shows the following **when the tunnel is active**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.9        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
37.139.23.49    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.9        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and the following **when the tunnel inactive**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Virtualbox configuration for Vms:

[image]

One of the VMs `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.0.3
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        network 172.16.0.0
        broadcast 172.16.255.255
        gateway 172.16.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: How are the networks of your VM's configured in VirtualBox?

Comment: bridges to eth0 - added info to the question.

Comment: I know it's not exactly the answer to your question, but for me it turned out to be easier to set up 2 VPN connections instead: 1 from the host machine, another from the guest machine

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will not work in a *Bridged Networking* setup. From the [VirtualBox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html):

> Bridged networking
>
> This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations 
>   and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox
>   connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network
>   packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network
>   stack.

Since your virtual machines are using `eth0` directly, they are unaware of the `tun0` interface to the tunnel running over it. You will need to use a different virtual networking configuration.

You have (among others) these options:

- *Network Address Translation (NAT)* is by far the simplest solution. VirtualBox will NAT the VMs across whatever internet connection is available to the host. This is fully transparent to the VMs. However this precludes connections from the host to the VMs or connections between the VMs.
- Use *Host-only Networking* to create a proper subnet containing the VMs and the host. This will require no changes in the interface configuration you now have in the VMs, but you will need to set up the host to be the gateway and router, *and* make it NAT the VMs to the outside (whether across its `eth0` or `tun0`).
- Combine the above: give each VM two interfaces, one gatewaying to the outside world (across VirtualBox's *NAT*) and the other attached to the *Host-Only LAN*.
- Try VirtualBox's experimental *NAT Networking* configuration.  **Update 2019:** this feature has since matured: attach to the host's NAT and choose the *Paravirtualized network (virtio-net)* adapter type.

Answer (score 68):

For VirtualBox with windows host and linux(mint) guest, go to the Network UI tab
and set for "Adapter" => "Attached to : NAT" and "Adapter type : Paravirtualized network". After that start your VM and you should be able to use VPN network.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks!  Using Ubuntu 16.04LTS as my guest and Windows 10 host, with Virtual Box 5.0.24.

Comment: Brilliant! This works for my Windows 10 host & VirtualBox (5.0.26) CentOS 7 guest.

Comment: Amazing! Should be the accepted answer. Was looking for this solution for ages. Thanks alot!

Comment: best answer here!

Comment: Why the heck isn't this the accepted answer? So easy and correct!

Comment: Mac 10.14 Host with Ubuntu Mate 18.04 guest in Virtualbox 6.0. Imported openvpn config and was able to connect with these settings - thanks!

Comment: Hmm did not work for me with windows 10 RHEL 7.4

Comment: This works for me though the icon on the Ubuntu taskbar still shows a question mark. And I have to manually set the proxy in my Ubuntu VM's Firefox browser.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn this isn't the accepted answer because the OP didn't want to wait two and a half years for (a) an answer and (b) a VirtualBox feature that didn't yet exist in Feb 2014. I'll update my answer to mention that the experimental feature has since become available as "paravirtualised network adapter".

Comment: As a clarification, the VM must be off before you can select "Paravirtualized Network" under the Advanced section

Comment: With this trick my Linux-VM does not loose the internet (browsing google.com and apt-get work) when I connect to the VPN on my Windows 10-Host, however it cant access the company websites,. So I asume it cant use the VPN of Host.

Comment: This worked for me with keeping only one network adapter enabled.

Comment: Worked great for me!

Comment: This works. Can anybody explain me *why* it works? how is a *paravirtualized* interface different from other interfaces?

Answer (score 15):

After looking for this solution everywhere, I finally found a working solution that doesn't require a lot of configuration changes and is really simple. Use the default NAT network and type this in the terminal:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnsproxy1 on
```

source: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13993

Comment: which terminal?

Comment: clarification: On host machine you have to execute command like: VBoxManage modifyvm "ubuntu18.04lts" --natdnsproxy1 on
 - please remember to replace "VM name" with the name of your VM

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. Here is how I solved it:

1. Change the network type of Guest System to be "Host Only"
2. Make the default gateway of Guest point to Host's ip `ifconfig vboxnet0` to find it.

Last step is routing the packets coming from vboxnet0 into your VPN.

If you route all traffic through VPN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 ! -d 192.168.5.0/24 -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.5
```

Where `10.8.0.5` is your tun0 gateway and `192.168.5.0/24` is your vboxnet0 network range.

If you only route certain traffic through VPN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 ! -d 192.168.5.0/24 -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.5
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 ! -d 192.168.5.0/24 -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.43.95
```

Where `10.8.0.5` is your tun0 gateway and `192.168.43.95` is your `wlan0`'s gateway and `192.168.5.0/24` is your vboxnet0 network range.

Note: This solution allow Guest OS be treated in same way Host OS is treated. Only IPs configured to go through VPN in Host OS will go through it in Guest.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some useful info for vagrant boxes using host vpn.
Basically you need to set natdnshostresolver1 option
**Note that this will *NOT* work when using the Vagrant's public_network setting though.**

```
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      # ---- other options....
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end
```

http://renier.morales-rodriguez.net/post/90674523562/sharing-host-vpn-with-virtualbox-guest
http://blog.geekslikeshinythings.com/2016/05/sharing-host-vpn-with-vagrant-rob-allen.html

Comment: The first link had the solution for me. It shows how to turn on the natdnshostresolver1 option for the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to https://askubuntu.com/a/419436/452891 and what worked for me was https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=494616&sid=3c7d05c98a79206d9cfa09f4910d9011#p494616 that also suggests to set the DNS servers in the host system in `resolv.conf` file.